# HttpMessageNotWritableException when testing with @SpringBootTest

Tags: spring-boot-test

I am trying to test a spring boot-based rest endpoint. Code is able to return the expected output but the test fails with following error:

Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedList] with preset Content-Type 'null']

Any ideas on this will be appreciated!

Here's the code for the same:

Controller ->

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {
    
    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;
    
    @GetMapping(value="students",produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Student>> getStudentDetails(){
        
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Student>>(studentService.getAllStudents(),HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Service class ->

```
@Service
public class StudentService {
    
    private List<Student> listOfStudents;
    
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        List<Student> list1= new LinkedList<Student>(); 
        Student s1 = new Student("a","S1");
        list1.add(s1);
        listOfStudents = list1;
    }
    
    public List<Student> getAllStudents(){
        return listOfStudents;
    }

}
```

Pojo ->

```
public class Student {

    private String sectionName;
    private String name;
    public String getRollNum() {
        return sectionName;
    }
    public void setRollNum(String rollNum) {
        this.sectionName = rollNum;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Student(String rollNum, String name) {
        this.sectionName = rollNum;
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [sectionName=" + sectionName + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }
    
    
}
```

Test ->

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {SampleController.class,StudentService.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class SampleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
    
    @Autowired
    SampleController sampleController;
    
    @MockBean
    StudentService studentService;
    
    @Test
    public void getAllUsersTest() throws Exception{
        List<Student> mockedList = new LinkedList<Student>();
        Student dummyStudent = new Student("dummy","Dummy Student");
        mockedList.add(dummyStudent);
        Mockito.when(studentService.getAllStudents()).thenReturn(mockedList);
        mockMvc.perform(get("/students")).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When manually configuring the `classes` attribute inside `@SpringBootTest`, Spring Boot's default auto-configuration will back off and you won't get an Spring TestContext with all your beans: `@SpringBootTest(classes = {SampleController.class,StudentService.class})`. This way your context lacks a lot of auto-configured beans like the JSON converter.

Either use `@SpringBootTest` without specifying `classes` to write an integration test with your entire Spring Context or use `@WebMvcTest`.

I guess for your test scenario, the sliced test annotation `@WebMvcTest(SampleController.class)` is what you are looking for. This will create a sliced Spring TestContext for you that only contains relevant Spring MVC components. It will also [auto-configure a `MockMvc` instance](https://rieckpil.de/guide-to-testing-spring-boot-applications-with-mockmvc/).

Comment: Thanks! This has worked out well for one example, but for a similar example, test fails with the message " Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ ContextConfiguration or @ SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test.

Comment: Can you update your question with the "similar example" where it fails. Did you also try to use `@WebMvcTest` instead of `@SpringBootTest`?